# 2005 Scion TC dead battery, cable location

Tags: jump-start, scion

Where do I connect the battery cables when jump starting

Battery is dead want to jump it not sure where to put cables

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that you are qualified to perform the procedure safely, just follow the jump starting directions in your owner's manual. Here are the three relevant pages.

[image]

[image]

[image]